# Make last children as first children using c# windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I want to manipulate children elements of my canvas to go back and bring to front

I have two buttons in my app

1. Send to Back
2. Bring to front

For Bring to front I am just removing it from canvas and adding it again it makes it to be in front.

```
DrawCanvas.Children.Remove(myimage);
DrawCanvas.Children.Add(myimage);
```

Now I want to make functionality of send to back. For this I had to make selected children as first element. How do I perform that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `Insert` method of the child collection a try:

```
DrawCanvas.Children.Remove( myimage );
DrawCanvas.Children.Insert( 0, myimage );
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.uielementcollection.aspx

Or even better:

```
DrawCanvas.Children.Move( DrawCanvas.Children.IndexOf( myimage ), 0 );
```

That should give better performance. Info at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.uielementcollection.move.aspx